# Where can I find out more about this bike with a spoke-less back wheel?

Tags: wheels, spokes, identify-this-bike

I saw this really cool, very unusual type of bike which does not use spokes for the back tire.

[image]

Can you please tell me if you are experienced and interested in such bikes how can I find one of those or build one. I've tried reversed image search engines like tineye.com but I couldn't find any results.

Furthermore if you are a fan of such type of bikes could you supply me with some 'juicy' links.

Comment: Kinda reminds me of the [motorcycle](http://www.imdb.com/media/rm1511557888/tt0796366) in the last [Star Trek](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0796366/) movie.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought myself!

Comment: fascinating - I wonder how the rim responds when hitting obstacles like potholes? Spokes provide a way to restore the rims shape, allowing a lighter weight rim. I would imagine a rim for this would want to be much stiffer since it is essentially being flattened by the two bottom rollers. And how easy would it be to change the tire on?

Answer (score 14):

#### The "Lunartic Cycle"

Here you go:

http://www.yankodesign.com/2010/08/13/no-spokes-cycle/

Complete with movie.

As for your extra reading material:

http://bicycledesign.net/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

"Experienced and/or interested": Not for real world use.

The regular spoked wheel is a very good and optimized solution to the "wheel" problem: light, stiff, low rolling resistance.

The shown wheel is more of a curiosity, something to startle people.

But, for sure, it is a good way to create potentially useful space "inside" the wheel...